# Can someone help me figure out why terminal (MacOS) will no longer find python files I have saved?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, new-operator

So I'm new to learning python. I have python 3.8.2 installed on my MacBook Pro. It was working fine for a week, and I was creating code in atom, saving as .py files to a folder on my desktop. Terminal was locating and running those files easy. However, now when I go into terminal it does not see that any of my files are in the folder, just a hello.py which prints "Hello World" but I do not have any such file in that folder.

For more background, I believe the source of the error is from my earlier command. I was unsure of how to quickly navigate terminal, and as I was in a folder in a folder and wanted to leave the second folder, I thought it was similar to those old command games were you tell them to do something. So in my dumb head I typed "MacBook-Pro:FolderName user$ exit foldername" then clicked return. After this I got a message that I didn't save so I don't remember it but it was a few more lines and I believe it said it exited. I could no longer type in terminal. I closed the shell and opened a new one and thats what lead to my current issue and why I am here seeking help.

I have included a photo of my atom code, what terminal says now and my folder of files terminal can't find.

Edit: I cannot include pictures yet due to reputation being low so it has been changed to a link [photo of issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXHWp.jpg)

EDIT: To add to this, I created a new save folder, moved one of the old files over to the new folder, and it ran normally. This leads me to believe that I used terminal to somehow ignore or forget that initial save folder and all its content. Is that a thing that can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your picture, it looks like the misconception is about how directories work in MacOS. In your terminal, you type `cd ~/py4e`; in Unix systems, `~` is your home directory, so you’re navigating to the `py4e` subdirectory under your home directory.

Then, however, you type `cd ~/ex_04` (or something), which means you’re trying to navigate to the ex_04 subdirectory under your home directory. This isn’t what you want; you want to navigate to ex_04 under the py4e directory.

In the Terminal, when you’re working in a current folder, you can change to another folder within that current directory by just typing the name of that subdirectory, i.e. `cd ex_04` once you have run `cd ~/py4e`.

If you’re just starting out with the command line in MacOS, I would definitely recommend looking up some beginner tutorials online so you can get a better feel of navigating and working in the Terminal.

Comment: Much appreciate the help. However, when I follow your recommendation, it still comes up with "no such file or directory" despite there clearly being in the initial (py4e) folder.

Am I wrong in assuming that I did something unintentionally to make terminal forget that folder's contents?

Comment: @Young You appear to have a `~/py4e` folder and also a `~/Desktop/py4e` folder, and you’re really interested in the latter.